# Which branch of the square root allows $(z^2)^{1/2} = z$

Tags: complex-analysis, branch-cuts

I am aware that $(z^2)^{1/2} = z$ does not hold for every branch of the function $f(z) = z^{1/2}$.

For example if we do not take a branch and consider $z=-1$, we get $$f((-1)^2) = \exp(\frac{1}{2}Log((-1)^2)) = exp(\frac{1}{2}Log(1) = \exp(0) = 1$$.

ie if we square and then square root -1, we do not get back to -1.

Is it possible to pick a branch of $f(z) = z^{1/2}$ such that when we do $f(z^2)$, we get back to the same root that we started with?

Thanks

Comment: Seems like you have the situation backwards, although what you said (also) seems true.  That is, I was taught to choose a convention for what I am to  regard as the principal branch of the square root function, and then determine for which values of $z$, the equation holds, and for which values of $z$ the equation does not hold.

Answer (score 1):

If the implicit universal quantifier is meant, i.e., "$(z^{2})^{1/2} = z$ for all complex $z$" then no, it's impossible: The squaring map $g(z) = z^{2}$ is not injective. For example, $g(1) = 1 = g(-1)$; no branch of square root can send $1$ back to both $1$ and $-1$.

Answer (score 0):

You need to choose the branch that gives you $\sqrt 1=-1$, which is not the principal one, but the one defined as
$$
F(z)=exp(\frac 1{2}[\ln |z|+i arg\,z+2\pi i]).
$$
Then, you end up with
$$
[(-1)^2]^{1/2}=exp(\pi i)=-1.
$$
In general, if you choose for $z$ an argument in $[0,2\pi)$, your relation will hold true with the principal branch if $arg\,z\in [0,\pi)$ and with the second branch if $arg\, z\in[\pi,2\pi)$.